# Error: Image Not Found when running Electrong-forge app on MacOs

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron, electron-forge

The .app make file made using electron-forge is failing in MacOS due to an image not being found. What on earth is this image it is referring to and how do I set it in electron-forge.

I have attempted to figure out how to use builder, but forge was much easier to setup. Forge made Windows and Linux executable no problem that ran with no issue. But mac is having an issue running it. 
The make file is created with the command 
        `electron-forge . --platform=darwin`
The error tells me that the tpr-software app needs some image but im not sure what that means since linux runs it with no issues. I guess I need to know if some image needs to be added and if so what is the best way to set it up for Forge.

tpr-software is the name of the app
Here is my error:

```
Process:               tpr-software [97502]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Documents/*/tpr-software.app/Contents/MacOS/tpr-software
Identifier:            com.electron.tpr-software
Version:               1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           tpr-software [97502]
User ID:               1508163232

Date/Time:             2019-10-16 13:26:11.045 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        CA9527E1-1C1D-D6F9-D810-579E972CD5F8


Time Awake Since Boot: 2500000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Documents/*/tpr-software.app/Contents/MacOS/tpr-software
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x102110000 -        0x102110ffb +com.electron.tpr-software (1.0.0 - 1.0.0) <0B17EBD3-270D-3C7F-A47F-A50793EC943D> /Users/USER/Documents/*/tpr-software.app/Contents/MacOS/tpr-software
       0x110458000 -        0x1104a29df  dyld (551.3) <AFAB4EFA-7020-34B1-BBEF-0F26C6D3CA36> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff4d066000 -     0x7fff4d066fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 22) <4CF8E31C-B5C7-367B-B73D-1A8AC8E41B7F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff4f96f000 -     0x7fff4fd35fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1452.23) <E64540AD-1755-3C16-8537-552A00E92541> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff5004b000 -     0x7fff500e6ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1445.50.26) <A63CAC8D-BF57-34FD-9A88-2F74546F2000> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff5963d000 -     0x7fff59965fff  com.apple.security (7.0 - 58286.51.6) <7212D257-5324-3DBA-8C26-504D6B8F632A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff59dcd000 -     0x7fff59e3dff3  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.17 - 1.17) <8532B8E9-7E30-35A3-BC4A-DDE8E0614FDA> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
```

main.js:

````
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = electron;

let mainWindow;
//Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', function(){
  //create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
    {
        webPreferences:{
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    }
  );
  //load html into window
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));



  //Build menu from Template
  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
  //Insert menu
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

// Create Menu Template
const mainMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu:[
      {
        label: 'Quit',
        accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Command+Q' :
        'Ctrl+Q',
        click(){
          app.quit();
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];```
````